# Proof related to Harmonic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

The question is as follows:

> Let $m_1<m_2<m_3<\cdots<m_k$ be postive integers such that $\frac{1}{m_1}$, $\frac{1}{m_2}$, $\frac{1}{m_3}$, $\cdots$, $\frac{1}{m_k}$ are in arithmetic progression. Then prove that $k<m_1+2$.

I am not sure how to tackle this problem. I tried taking the common differences, but I can't seem to be able to arrive at the final expression. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ISI B. Stat/B. Math Entrance 2015 subjective Problem?

Comment: @user355304 I'm not sure of the source. It's been forwarded to me.

Comment: See [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c76361_2015_isi_entrance_examination).

Comment: And [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1087266p4813481) is the discussion on this problem.

Comment: @user355304 Thanks for the links but I think it's gonna take a while to find a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: @user355304 The tag description says the question must be from any of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_competitions#India) contests. Entrance tests aren't mentioned, so I'm not sure.

Comment: The only proof that is almost OK among those on the link provided by @user355304 contains a flaw, in that in a crucial step it implicitly assumed that $\frac1{r(m_1+1)} \leq m_1$, where $r$ is the difference between the reciprocals ($1/m_1 - 1/m_2 = r$).  I see no reason nor given argument why that must be so; $r$ might be very small.

Comment: @MarkFischler That statement is valid. I skip some arithmetic: $$\frac{1}{r(m_1+1)}=\frac{1}{1+1/m_1-(m_1+1)/m_2}=\frac{m_1}{m_1+1-m_1(m_1+1)/m_2}$$ Hence it is true if $m_1+1-m_1(m_1+1)/m_2\ge 1$ which means $m_1m_2\ge m_1(m_1+1)$ which is obviously the case.

Comment: @MarkFischler, that step is totally valid. You see that $$\frac1{m_1}-r=\frac1{m_2}\le\frac1{1+m_1}\\\implies \frac1{m_1}-r\le \frac 1{1+m_1}\\\implies 1-m_1r\le \frac{m_1}{1+m_1}=1-\frac1{1+m_1}\\\implies m_1r\ge\frac1{1+m_1}\\\implies \frac1{m_1r}\le 1+m_1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the arithmetic progression, starting with $\frac1{m_1}$, contains $k$ positive terms.  Now the (uniform) term difference is 
$$
d = \frac{1}{m_1} - \frac{1}{m_2}
\\ m_2 \geq m_1+1 \implies d \geq \frac{1}{m_1} - \frac{1}{m_1+1}=\frac{1}{m_1(m_1+1)}
$$
The entire sequence, which ends in a positive value $\frac{1}{m_k}$, consists of $k-1$ steps of size $d$.
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{m_1}-(k-1)\frac{1}{m_1(m_1+1)} = \frac{1}{m_k} >0 \\
\frac{1}{m_1} > (k-1)\frac{1}{m_1(m_1+1)}
\\ 1 > (k-1)\frac{1}{m_1+1}
\\ m_1+1 > k-1 \implies k < m+2
$$

Comment: I feel this is the most concise solution. That's why I'm accepting it. Other answers deserve equal merit as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are in arithmetic progression let us call $1/m_n-1/m_{n+1}=L>0$. We then have that
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{m_n}-\frac{1}{m_{n+1}}\right) &= \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}L \\
&= (k-1)L \\
&= \frac{1}{m_1}-\frac{1}{m_k}
\end{align}$$
Which means we just have to show
$$k=\frac{\frac{1}{m_1}-\frac{1}{m_k}}{L}+1<m_1+2\qquad (1)$$
Multiply both sides by $m_1$
$$\frac{1-\frac{m_1}{m_k}}{L}<m_1(m_1+1)$$
Multiply by $L=1/m_1-1/m_2$ and move around some terms
$$\begin{align}
1 &<Lm_1(m_1+1)+\frac{m_1}{m_k} \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{m_1}-\frac{1}{m_2}\right)m_1(m_1+1)+\frac{m_1}{m_k} \\
&=m_1+1-\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_2}+\frac{m_1}{m_k}
\end{align}$$
Hence we for $(1)$ to be true we only need to show
$$\begin{align}
0 &< m_1+\frac{m_1}{m_k}-\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_2} & (2) \\
&= m_1+\frac{m_1}{m_k}-\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_1+x} & x\ge 1
\end{align}$$
Notice that because $x\ge 1$ we have
$$\begin{align}
m_1+\frac{m_1}{m_k}-\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_1+x} &\ge m_1+\frac{m_1}{m_k}-\frac{m_1(m_1+1)}{m_1+1} \\
&=\frac{m_1}{m_k} \\
&> 0
\end{align}$$
Thus we see that $(2)$ holds and tracing back our work we see that this implies our original inequality, $(1)$, holds.

Answer (score 2):

It is important in this problem to understand that the maximun number $k$ is determined by the choice of the two first integers $m_1,m_2$.

Let $m_1$ and $m_2=m_1+h$ (where $h\ge 1$); the common difference of the a. p. is $d=\frac{-h}{m_1(m_1+h)}$ so we have $$u_1=\frac{1}{m_1}\\u_2=\frac{1}{m_1+h}\\u_3=\frac{1}{m_1+h}+\frac{-h}{m_1(m_1+h)}=\frac{m_1-h}{m_1(m_1+h)}\\u_4=\frac{m_1-2h}{m_1(m_1+h)}\\u_5=\frac{m_1-3h}{m_1(m_1+h)}\\....\\....\\u_k=\frac{m_1-(k-2)h}{m_1(m_1+h)}$$ The progression stop when $u_k$ is not anymore positive. Meanwhile one has
$$m_1-(k-2)h\gt 0\iff m_1\gt(k-2)h\ge k-2$$ 
Thus $$k\lt m_1+2$$