# Asymptotic growth of l.c.m. of all integers below $k$

Tags: asymptotics, gcd-and-lcm

In a recent question [Proof related to Harmonic Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867860/proof-related-to-harmonic-progression/1867998#1867998) it was shown that if $m_1, m_2 \ldots m_k$ are positive integers such that $m_1 < m_2 < \ldots < m_k$ and 
$$
\left\{\frac1{m_1}, \frac1{m_2}, \ldots ,\frac1{m_k} \right\} 
$$ 
form an arithmetic progression, then 
$$
m_1 \geq k-1
$$
For $k \in \{2,3,4\}$ this bound in fact is saturated.  For example, 
$$
\left\{ \frac13, \frac14, \frac16,\frac1{12} \right\}
$$ are an arithmetic progression, so $m_1 (k=4)$ can be $3$.

For a given sequence length $k$ let $m(k)$ be the smallest value of $m_1$ such that such an arithmetic progression of reciprocals of length $k$ can be formed starting from $\frac1{m_1}$. So for example,
$$
m(2) = 1 \\
m(3) = 2 \\
m(4) = 3 \\
m(5) = m(6) = 10 \\
m(7) = 60\\
m(8) = 105 \\ \vdots
$$

I'd like to know the asymptotic expression for $m(k)$ for large $k$.  $m(k)$ will in most cases be the least common multiple of $1, 2, 3, \ldots k$ divided by $k$. in some cases such as $k=6$ $m(k)=m(k-1)$ but still the statement about
$$
m(k) = \frac{\operatorname{l.c.m.} (n\mid 1<n\leq k)}{k}
$$
almost holds true; for the lesser $k$ (for example, $k=5$) the denominator is $k+1$ instead of $k$.

But while I know the asymptotics of $k!$ (Stirling's approximation) and this g.c.d. is sort of related to $k!$, I don't know the asymptotics of this l.c.m.

Comment: $lcm(1, \ldots, k) = \prod_{p \le k} p^{\lfloor \frac{\ln k}{\ln p} \rfloor}$ so $\ln lcm(1, \ldots, k) = \sum_{p \le k} \lfloor \frac{\ln k}{\ln p} \rfloor \ln p = \sum_{p,m, p^m \le k} \ln p = \psi(k) = k + o(k)$ [by the prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) (in number theory, $\sum_p$  stands for "sum over every prime numbers")

Comment: Yes, that works.  And it brings up another question:  The function, defined on $k\in \Bbb{Z}, k >1$ as $f(k) =\log( \mbox{ lcm }(1,\ldots,k))/k$ is usually less than 1, but sometimes slightly greater than 1.  What is the maximum attained by $f(k)$?  For example, there is a locally high value at $k=31$ and another at $k=109$.

Comment: I told you, $\frac{\psi(k)}{k} \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$, it is exactly the prime number theorem