# $\sup\left(\frac{\log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))}{k}\right)$ for $k\in \Bbb{Z}, k>1$

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, least-common-multiple

In a previous question [Asymptotic growth of l.c.m. of all integers below $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870780/asymptotic-growth-of-l-c-m-of-all-integers-below-k), it was noted that using the Prime Number Theorem you can prove that
$$ \log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k)) =k+\mbox{ o}(k)$$

Examining the values of $ \log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))/k$, one finds that

- They take an upward jump at each prime and to a lesser extent at each prime power.
- They are near to $1$ once $k$ goes above $4$, but are usually just below $1$.
- The occasional excursions above $1$ occur after high concentrations of primes, for example, when twin primes (or a prime gap of $4$ immediately following a twin prime) force the log to grow faster than the increase in $k$ can push it down.

Certain values of $k$ produce values of $ \log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))/k$ that are higher than that for any lower $k$.  The sequence of such values starts with 
$$
2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,19,31,109,113
$$

I am interested in two related properties:

Is there some finite value $\eta$ 
$$\eta = \sup\left(\frac{\log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))}{k}\right)$$
 for $k\in \Bbb{Z}, k>1$

such that for all $k$, $ \log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))/k \leq \eta$?

And if there is such a bound, does the equality hold (in which case the 
sequence of "best $k$ thus far" is finite) or does the best value of 
$ \log(\mbox{ lcm }(1,2,\ldots,k))/k$ up to  $k_0$ approach $\eta$ as $k_0 \to \infty$ but never get there?

Comment: I told you, don't write $lcm(1,\ldots,k)$ but $\psi(k) = \sum_{p^m \le k} \log p$ the second [Chebyshev funciton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). And read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem you'll see that from any numerical bound for the $o(k)$ term you can deduce $\sup_k \frac{\psi(k)}{k}$ by testing it for every $k$ until you find one $> 1$ and  greater than the bound.

Comment: @user1952009: From the known properties of the Chebyshev function, $\psi(x)/x \leq \psi(113)/113 \approx 1.038823$.  So that answers both the questions.  There is a finite upper bound, and the equality sign holds.